# Как отправить почту smtp Google, чтобы это письмо не попадало в папку исходящие?

Tags: gmail

Есть задача, сделать так, чтобы при отправки письма через smtp Google это письмо не попадало в папку исходящие в почтовом ящике гугла.

Подскажите как решить?

Отправляю с такими параметрами:

```
'protocol'      => 'smtp',
'smtp_host'     => 'smtp.googlemail.com',
'smtp_user'     => 'mymail@gmail.com',
'smtp_pass'     => 'pass',
'smtp_port'     => '587',
'smtp_crypto'   => 'tls'
```

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего вам сюда - [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/)

Есть много библиотек, в том числе и для PHP - [Gmail API Client Libraries](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/downloads), [PHP Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/php)

Судя по методам API, есть возможность удаления - [Users.messages: delete](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/delete)